# Why we cannot provide ID(#) selector in Angular 2 directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

We can create directives using following selectors in Angular 2

1. Property:  `selector:'[myDir]'`
     Consumption:  `<h1 myDir></h1>`
2. Class:  `selector:'.myDir'`
     Consumption:  `<h1 class="myDir"></h1>`
3. Element:  `selector:'myDir'`
     Consumption:  `<myDir></myDir>`

Then why we cannot create directives using Id (#)

```
  selector : '#myDir'
```

Comment: because it's not supported. You can as well add an unique attribute value to get the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

We can not declare an angular directive using **ID(#)** css selector, because it restricts the **reusability** which is one of the most important feature of components/directives.

if we declare the directive using **#myDir** selector then we can use it only once on the page, because in w3c standards its clearly mentioned that no two ID attributes can have the same value in a conformant document, regardless of the type of the elements that carry them.

For more info see [w3c draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#id-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported.
The only way to create a directive is through unique attribute.

The CSS selector (ID) is not a valid identifier of an element, anyway it is not a unique for HTML and CSS also.

Comment: Its not restircted to only attributes..you can create directives using above provided selectors also

Comment: I see that. But, my thought is that `class` is made available for directives since a element can have any number of directives. ID should be unique to an element by `De facto` rule of HTML. That was the logic behind this design.